# Scalable way of handling font definitions in React.js application

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, fonts, styled-components

Usually in my code there are few distinct fonts I'm using with some variants like:

- Arial, font-weight: 400, font-style: normal
- Arial, font-weight: 400, font-style: italic
- Arial, font-weight: 700, font-style: normal
- Helvetica, font-weight: 400, font-style: normal
- Helvetica, font-weight: 400, font-style: italic

I'm using CSS-IN-JS library `styled-components` for that, so not using some `styles.css`. Sometimes designer comes to me and asks to change e.g. `Arial` to `Comic Sans` for `font-style: italic;` and `font-weight: 400;`

This can't be code by simple replacing across the project codebase as there are other variants of this font.

I want to minimise the amount of work needed to incorporate that change, thus need to isolate those font objects in one place.

**QUESTION :**

**I've devised 3 approaches for this and 3rd one seems to be the best one, but please advice from your experience. Maybe there are some extra cons or pros to each of those specified below?**

**APPROACHES :**

**First approach**

I thought about extracting those text definitions into separate `style-components`, like:

```
const ArialGeneral = styled.span`
  font-family: Arial;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
`

const ArialNormal = styled(ArialGeneral)``
const ArialNormalItalic = styled(ArialGeneral)`
  font-style: italic;
`
```

And then wrapping all text occurrences with relevant style.

```
...
<HeroText>
  <ArialNormal>
    Welcome to our system!
  </ArialNormal>
</HeroText>
...
```

**Cons** of this are:

- Extra JSX tags
- Maybe some computational cost to re-render those extra components along with CSS computations by browser

**Pros:**

- I will have 1 place to govern all occurrences of any given `[font-family, font-style, font-weight]` combination

**Second approach**

Use the same technic, but instead of defining `styled-component`s use global `styles.css` with basically same definitions in form of classes e.g.:

```
.font-arial-normal {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

This will require to decorate text elements with some classes e.g.:

```
...
<HeroText className="font-arial-normal">
  Welcome to our system!
</HeroText>
...
```

**Cons:**

- Using two formats CSS-in-JS and `styles.css`
- Addition of `classNames` to JSX

**Pros:**

- In contrast with variant 1, will not require resources for additional JSX compilation
- Same benefit as in variant 1

**Third approach**

I've see in this article [WebType Best practices for using font-weights](https://www.webtype.com/info/articles/fonts-weights/) and also in examples for web-fonts packages I'm downloading that each combination of `[font-family, font-style, font-weight]` is defined as a separate font e.g. like in this example from mentioned resource (Assuming those are all `font-style: normal;`):

```
{ font-family: "Interstate Light"; font-weight: normal; }
{ font-family: "Interstate Medium"; font-weight: normal; }
{ font-family: "Interstate Regular"; font-weight: normal; }
{ font-family: "Interstate Semibold"; font-weight: bold; }
{ font-family: "Interstate Bold"; font-weight: bold; }
{ font-family: "Interstate Extrabold"; font-weight: bold; }
{ font-family: "Interstate Black"; font-weight: bold; }
```

**Cons:**

- Requires more initial work (but those webfont packages already provide the needed css)

**Pros:**

- We are not using anything more then `fonts.css` where we define fonts (I use this in all variants) thus eliminating the `using two formats CSS-in-JS and styles.css` issues from second method
- Can be used in JS-IN-CSS as I'm using it now and codebase-wide replace will change only those fonts (what I'm trying to achieve), so the same benefit as in variant 1

Comment: 3rd solution is what I use in my projects. Would recommend you to abstract away the font-family name. Say you are using a certain type of font-family with particular font-weight for all your headers, call it 'HeaderFont'. This way you don't have to change the name of the font-family everywhere you are using it and you can simply get away by changing the internal font-family in that one place only.

Comment: @DanglingCruze Thank you for comment. What do you do when your abstraction suddenly refers to more components then header, let's says after change of mind of designer? Will you create new font with different name but with same definition? Or will you rename it?

Comment: for the second approach, maybe i am being pedantic but instead of `className` you can just regular html `class` if you use `babel-plugin-react-html-attrs`

Comment: I will take time initially to figure out the sets of related and un-related components. Then define some global fonts and some related name-spaced fonts. There will be times when you will have to rename but chances of that will be very less. What you will generally get is change the font category of a particular component to a different one which I have already defined. So, I will just change the font abstraction it belonged to.

Answer (score 4):

I think the biggest thing you need answer is *where* the font variants will take place inside your app. Are they global? Do you only need them for certain tags (i.e. `h1`, `h2`, etc)? Do you need specific overrides specific to few components?

In my experience, generally you only declare 1 or 2 fonts per app, and these generally tend to be app-wide. Its rare that I see these fonts used very specifically (i.e. 1 or 2 elements with a specific class or ID), and rather tend to be placed on `body`.

**First approach**

Assuming that are only using a single font family (i.e. "Arial", "open sans", etc), the first approach will be very hard to scale. As you mentioned, not only does it create a lot of noise, but if you name the component after the font name, it will quickly get out of date the moment you switch font families. This will require quite a few edits to your application. I don't recommend this approach unless you enjoy editing many many files when it comes time to update.

**Second approach**

This approach is a little bit better since you have now cut down on the HTML noise, but you have gained very little here. You still suffer from the same problem as the first approach, just in a slightly different form. Changing fonts likely means renaming the class selector, which also means updating any component that uses that class name.

**Third approach**

This is the closet approach to solving your needs in my opinion, though it does seem you want to keep everything inside of styled-components as much as possible. This being the case, I would tweak this approach slightly.

**Alternate approach**

I believe the `@font-face` approach paired with styled-component's [`injectGlobal`](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/api#injectglobal) API is going to get you the most mileage (they even mention `@font-face` in the docs!)

Swapping out font-families means updating your `@font-family` definition and updating your `font-family` declaration all in one go. Better yet, you avoid `.css` files and keep everything within styled-components!

Again, assuming your goal is to target font app-wide, with maybe a variant on a tag or two (`h2`, `h2`, etc), this allows you to make all of your edits in 1 place and I believe best accomplishes your goal.

Take a look at the [`@font-face`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face) documentation to get a feel for declaring your font styles in case you aren't familiar with it. I know there are plenty of resources out there to help guide you declaring `@font-face` as well (assuming you aren't using something like Google fonts already).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use [`css`](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/api#css) and [`.extend`](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#extending-styles) to solve this problem?

**[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/znkzvmv1wp)**

```
import styled, { css } from 'styled-components';

const apply = (tag, styles) => {
  return styled[tag]`${styles}`.extend
};

// BASE STYLES

const arial400 = css`
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: 400;
`;

const arial400italic = css`
  ${arial400};
  font-style: italic;
`;

const helveticaNormal = css`
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-weight: normal;
`;

const helveticaItalicBold = css`
  ${helveticaNormal};
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: bold;
`;

const HeroText = apply('h2', arial400italic)`
  color: red;
`;

const FancyButton = apply('button', helveticaItalicBold) `
  color: white;
  background: indigo;
  padding: 10px;
`;
```

...

```
<div>
  <HeroText>Welcome to our system!</HeroText>
  <FancyButton>CLICK ME</FancyButton>
</div>
```

...

**Another approach?**

Important part of this approach is a `apply` function, that create the new styled-component with a basic styles.

First, you need to describe the basic styles.
Second, using the `apply` function, you simply extend the base style with custom styles which need for specific case (if that needed).

**Pros:**

- using weird `apply` function instead of classic "styled" way

**Cons:**

- no require extra JSX tags
- one place for *global* styles, which can easily extend each other
- because *global* styles still be a "styled components" that means you can use props
- easy to extend existing styles, all you need just to replace `styled.tag` to `apply('tag', baseStyles)`

Comment: please see description of bounty `Nobody clarified cons and pros of stated variants. only answer proposed one more variant but lacks pros and cons.`. You've proposed new variant, but please describe it more in specified way. Also how your variant relates to other variants - maybe other way has some advantages over it, and some other have disadvantages. **I see that it's clarification of variant 1 BTW :)**

Answer (score 2):

I don't entirely agree with the pros and cons stated above. Most of these are related to CSS vs CSS-IN-JS. Having CSS is perfectly fine in styled-components. My thumb rule is to use CSS for generic classes and style-components for theming and variables. Rest use whatever you feel is less awkward and maintainable.

Coming to your specific problem of maintaining fonts and font-weight changes.

I have faced similar issues few times.

Platforms with themes support, design iteration or even at hackathons.

You mostly find yourself changing these with same design language at top level.
i.e changing your primary font and weight in the app entirely.

so, Have your fonts defined with @font-face with primary, secondary, tertiary etc instead of specific font-name as you would be have to change just the definition instead of the classnames everywhere.

```
   @font-face {
     font-family: "primary-default";
     font-weight:  regular
     src: url("/fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.woff2") format("woff2"),
          url("/fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.woff") format("woff");
   }
```

If you would have to change primary-default to have a different font-family and weight you can modify these definitions accordingly.

If it is just a specific changes or quick overrides then use helper classes

```
 .primary-fontStyle {
   font-family: "primary-default";
   font-weight:  regular
 }
```

Comment: please see description of bounty Nobody clarified cons and pros of stated variants. only answer proposed one more variant but lacks pros and cons.. You've proposed new variant, but please describe it more in specified way. Also how your variant relates to other variants - maybe other way has some advantages over it, and some other have disadvantages.

Comment: @zmii, Sure i updated my answer. I use a combination of approaches close to second and third.

Answer (score 1):

You can have one option to use props with theming support. You can pass the required values through props otherwise use default values.
Here is sample,

```
const General = styled.span`
  ... // other properties
  font-family: ${ props => props.theme.fontFamily };
  font-style: ${ props => props.theme.fontStyle };  
  font-weight: ${ props => props.theme.fontWeight };
`
```

With reference to the 3rd approach, we can have the combination of `[font-family, font-style, font-weight]`. 
Component behavoiur depends on the combination passed as props to it.

```
let arialNoraml300 = { 
  fontFamily: Arial,
  fontStyle: normal,
  fontWeight: 300
};

let helveticaOblique900 = { 
  fontFamily: Helvetica, 
  fontStyle: oblique, 
  fontWeight: 900 
}

... // other combinations
```

Its can be used as `<General theme={arialNoraml300} />` or `<General theme={helveticaOblique900} />`

If we asked any change, we need to replace the combination passed to component.

Hope it help you.

Comment: I think that this will create more mess for the specific use case I'm asking about. (`styled-components` theming also produces similar kind of code). Imagine you have 1000 components that have this kind of dynamic resolution of triade `[font-family, font-style, font-weight]`. **Can you please update your answer with description of what would you do when your designed will come to you and ask to change `[font-family: Arial, font-style: normal, font-weight: 300]` to `[font-family: Helvetica, font-style: oblique, font-weight: 900]` ?** Will this be simple find-and-replace in your codebase?

Comment: I upvoted this as this is fourth interesting variant. @Harish thank you for input. Can you update answer with pros and cons of this approach and compare it with other variants?

Comment: thank you for input. Can you update answer with pros and cons of this approach and compare it with other variants?